# Strange behaviour of raise Sympy's rsolve with fractional coefficients

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following issue with Sympy when trying to solve difference (recursive) equations. When the free terms are integers, everything is OK, e.g.

```
y = sym.Function('y')
t = sym.symbols('t',integer=True)
f = y(t)- 1/3*y(t-1) - 9
eq_sol = sym.rsolve(f,y(t))
eq_sol
```

But if a coefficient is a decimal or a fraction, such as here (9 changes to 9.1),

```
y = sym.Function('y')
t = sym.symbols('t',integer=True)
f = y(t)- 1/3*y(t-1) - 9.1
eq_sol = sym.rsolve(f,y(t))
eq_sol
```

an error appears:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_27564/4249747763.py in <module>
      2 t = sym.symbols('t',integer=True)
      3 f = y(t)- 1/3*y(t-1) - 9.1
----> 4 eq_sol = sym.rsolve(f,y(t))
      5 eq_sol

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\recurr.py in rsolve(f, y, init)
    741                     h_part[int(result[k])].append(coeff)
    742                     continue
--> 743             raise ValueError(
    744                 "'%s(%s + k)' expected, got '%s'" % (y.func, n, h))
    745     for k in h_part:

ValueError: 'y(t + k)' expected, got '9.10000000000000'
```

I would be grateful to those who could provide a hint.

Comment: This is a bug that should be reported to github: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Comment: As a workaround you can use `Rational('9.1')`

Comment: Note that it is generally better to use exact numbers rather than floats.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, Oscar Benjamin! That did the trick:

```
y = sym.Function('y')
t = sym.symbols('t',integer=True)
f = y(t)- 1/3*y(t-1) - Fraction(9,2) # different number here, not 9.1
eq_sol = sym.rsolve(f,y(t))
eq_sol
```

Comment: Note that Python will convert `1/3` to a float before sympy gets the chance to create a fraction.  So you might want to also explicitly convert it to a fraction.

Comment: Thanks! I notice that after I posted, and I will have it in mind for future stuff.